# C# : Need to get Datable id column into list of string

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

C# : Need to get Data table id column into list of string

```
List<string> ids = new List<string>();
ids  = dtTable.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(dr => dr.Field<string>("GROUP_ID"))
              .Where(dr => dr != null).ToList();
```

I get this error :

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.

If I change the type to int then it can't handle `null` values so I have give the type as string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cast column values as `int?` and ignore `null`s

```
var ids = dtTable.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
              .Select(dr => dr.Field<int?>("GROUP_ID"))
              .Where(i => i.HasValue)
              .Select(i => i.Value)
              .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you that int? helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the column `GROUP_ID` is of type `int`. You can do two things: Convert all the values in this column to `string`, or create a list of `int`.

To create a list of `int`:

```
List<int> ids = new List<int>();
ids  = dtTable.Rows
    .OfType<DataRow>() // Select all rows.
    .Select(dr => dr.Field<int?>("GROUP_ID")) // Select all nullable ID's. 
    .Where(id => id != null) // Remove all null's.
    .Select(id => id.Value) // Convert all values from int? to int.
    .ToList(); // Put all values in a list.
```

Or... to convert all values to strings:

```
List<string> ids = new List<string>();
ids  = dtTable.Rows
    .OfType<DataRow>() // Select all rows.
    .Select(dr => dr.Field<int?>("GROUP_ID").ToString()) // Select all nullable ID's and turn them into strings.
    .Where(id => id != null) // Remove all null's.
    .ToList(); // Put all values in a list.
```

By the way: Reevaluate your `Where(dr => dr != null).` It looks like you want to verify if the row is null or not. But all rows are never null. It actually checks if the ID is null.

Comment: I need the rows which has values not the null values.It throws error like -  Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Int32'. Please use a nullable type. As it has null values.

Comment: I modified my answer. I did not know if the ID's where DBNull or not. Modify the `Field<int>`  into  `Field<int?>`.

Answer (score 0):

you cant convert int to string.. very clear

```
 .Where(dr => dr != null).Select(dr => dr.Field<int>("GROUP_ID").ToString())
```

use type as int and then use to-string to convert value to string

Comment: It throws error like -  Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Int32'. Please use a nullable type. As it has null values

Comment: you need to change where you are checking for null.. updated the answer